# java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets exception while trying to connect to pc localhost

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I had this code and it ran successfully on an AVD:

```
package com.mohammadfs.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.e("M3", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection connection = DriverManager.
                            getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://192.168.1.7:3306/fun", "root", "bingo");
                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from people");
                    if(resultSet.next()) {
                        Log.d("M3", resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3) + " " +
                                resultSet.getString(4));
                    }
                }
                catch(SQLException e) {
                    Log.e("M3", e.getMessage() + "\n");
                    for(StackTraceElement element: e.getStackTrace()) {
                        Log.e("M3", "   " + element.toString());
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("M3", "WTF!");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

But when on a physical device I got
`No suitable driver`
error, so first I added
`Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")`
before creating the connection variable, and changed the ip address to laptop
local IPv4 in my case:
`192.168.1.7`
and then this exception appeared:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5122
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.result.ErrorPacket.<init>(ErrorPacket.java:76)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.read.ReadInitialConnectPacket.<init>(ReadInitialConnectPacket.java:88)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:418)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:358)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:713)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:471)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:209)
    at com.mohammadfs.sample.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

so I searched and didn't find any matching question but I concluded from answer
to another question that it may be because of minimum SDK because my phone is of API level 17 and the emulator I use run a API 23 version.

**EDIT**
as @CommonsWare answered and I've guessed, it is because of required SDK!
Also I know it is better using web services for such a job but at the moment I can't do that way.
Any workaround would be helpful and appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`StandardCharsets` was added in API Level 19. If you need to use this library, you will need to set your `minSdkVersion` to 19 or higher.

Comment: @MaskedMan: "Isn't there any workaround?" -- don't use the library. JDBC is not a very good idea from mobile devices in the first place. Or, if this library is open source, fork it and remove the dependency on `StandardCharsets` (though then there may be other missing classes besides this one). Or, ask the maintainers of the library if they plan on supporting older Android versions.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error when running tomcat 
you have conflict between JDK and JRE version.

in my case i changed the JDK form
1.7
to 
1.6.0
and the error was fixed.
(my JRE version : 1.7)

Comment: I didn't get it, I wasn't using Tomcat!
Thanks however :)